# List<Object> throwing error saying the element is not found

Tags: c#

```cs
List<int> totalrisks = data.GroupBy(rec => rec.Month)
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => x.Where(o=>o.RiskCategory == "High")
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .TotalRisks)
    .ToList();
```

This code works fine when there is a riskcategory element with a value High.

If there is no risk category called High, its throwing up an error. How to handle this? If there is no High category I want the TotalRisk to be 0.

Comment: You can improve performance and memory use by removing the middle `ToList()` call.

Comment: So provide your own default value to be used in `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: how to provide 0 as the default value if there is no such element with the value High?

Comment: probably `FirstOrDefault()?.TotalRisks ?? 0` will do.

Comment: What are you trying to do and why is `ToList()` used in the middle? Covering up query bugs by loading an entire table in memory isn't going to solve anything. It *will* cause severe production problems though as the code tries to read all columns from eg a 100K row-table when it only seems to need a few numbers. This will block other connections that are trying to modify that table while this query is reading everything

Comment: What exactly is your error message? The title suggests "element was not found" but I'm not sure how that would occur in this code.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` without an actual order returns essentially random values that could change between calls, so the query is wrong from the start. In a database there's *no* implied order without an explicit `ORDER BY` clause. This means that `data.GroupBy(rec => rec.Month).ToList()` will return rows in any order that's cheapest for the server. The `GroupBy` clause will only reshape the results by `Month`, it won't sort them by any other property.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably this operation is producing the error:

```
x.Where(o=>o.RiskCategory == "High").FirstOrDefault().TotalRisks
```

If there are no matching elements found in the `.Where()` operation, then `FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` (for reference types).  And you can't read properties from `null`.

You can use the `null` conditional operator, in combination with the `null` coalescing operator, to check for `null` and provide a default otherwise:

```
x.Where(o=>o.RiskCategory == "High").FirstOrDefault()?.TotalRisks ?? 0
```

So when used within the `Select` operation this should provide you with the "first or default" `TotalRisks` value for the matching category, or `0` when there is no such matching category.

Comment: Given there's no explicit `OrderBy` the results may be unexpected even if there's no error